# Subtract two result sets SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
Result1     Result2
a           a
b           b    
a
```

How to obtain `a` by doing a subtraction between these two result sets. `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` return nothing for these two result sets. But i want `a` to be returned. Pleas help!

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Suppose the first result set had three `a` records.  What output would you want then?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, SQL 2012. If `Result1` has 3 `a`s then 2`a`s should get returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . This is tricky because you want to take counts into account.  One method would be:

```
select r1.col, r1.cnt - coalesce(r2.cnt, 0)
from (select col, count(*) as cnt
      from result1
      group by col
     ) r1 left join
     (select col, count(*) as cnt
      from resuult2
      group by col
    ) r2
    on r1.col = r2.col
where r1.cnt > coalesce(r2.cnt, 0);
```

This doesn't return exactly what you want, but it might suffice.  Another method would use `row_number()`:

```
select r1.col
from (select col, row_number() over (partition by col order by col) as seqnum
      from result1
      group by col
     ) r1 left join
     (select col, row_number() over (partition by col order by col) as seqnum
      from resuult2
      group by col
    ) r2
    on r1.col = r2.col and r1.seqnum = r2.seqnum
where r2.col is null;
```

Comment: Thank you sir!. Tried first method and gave the expected result. Method two, yet to try.

Answer (score 4):

With standard SQL, you can use the `except all` operator for that:

```
select *
from table_one
except all
select * 
from table_two
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d998c/1

Note that if you had `a` two times in `table_one` the above query would return it two times as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This gives me the error when executing, `The 'ALL' version of the EXCEPT operator is not supported`. What would be the reason?

Comment: @Isuru: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: `sql server management studio 2012`. If it is working i think your way is more simpler to handle sir.

Comment: @Isuru: then it seems SQL Server does not support EXCEPT ALL

Comment: Is it a version problem? again thanks for the knowledge.

Comment: @Isuru: no idea. I don't use SQL Server

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name, So which DBMS does this supports sir? It's for the knowledge.

Comment: @Isuru: Postgres as shown in the SQLFiddle. And I know that DB2, Apache Derby and HSQLDB support it as well. Probably others also.